# 3 Questions concerning GAP 4 and the Heller module

Tags: group-theory, gap

I am a student of mathematics who has difficulties with GAP 4. I unfortunately don't know how to do the following things:

1) I wish to compute the Heller module of the trivial module in the Kleinian Four Group

2) I'd like to enter a module in GAP when some matrices which reflect the group elements' actions are given (e.g. like in exercise 13 on page 24 (31 of 109) of Benson's paper http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/1107/1107.4815v1.pdf)

3) I want to calculate with an algebraic closure of F_p in GAP - is there a way to implement this?

I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: You may have some luck with answers here; but if you do not, consider the GAP Forum mailing list instead. See [the GAP forum page](http://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/Forum/forum.html).

Comment: @Arturo: Thank you for your comment. I think, I'll do that if I don't get answers here.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the first Heller translate of the trivial module? If so, it is relatively easy to describe, and is the unique maximal submodule of the regular module for the Klein 4-group: in other words, the augmentation ideal. It does not really require GAP to find all you need to know about the group action on this module.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to be able to enter and calculate with more complicated groups (and group algebras, modules, projective resolutions,...) in GAP. Since I know what the first Heller translate of the trivial modul has to look like, when I consider the group V_4, I wanted to start with that example.

Comment: @Lisa123: Noted. I am not really the person to answer such questions.